# PAYPAL REST API: How do you bill with a vaulted credit card

Tags: api, rest, paypal

Using the PAYPAL REST API, I was able to successfully (1) Vault a credit card and (2) Lookup the vaulted credit card information.

After you lookup the Vaulted Credit Card and receive Paypal's response; however, do you re-use that response data to create a transaction in the future?

```
#How to Look up the Vaulted Credit Card
curl -v [link removed]/CARD-8TT93830P06829326KIOO3XI -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer O912TKmsB8WRsgdNrNrJAmlCqF5kLdEl.re3z4Kmp8M"

#Paypal's Response to the Lookup Request
{"id":"CARD-8TT93830P06829326KIOO3XI","valid_until":"2016-08-26T00:00:00Z","state":"ok","payer_id":"user12345","type":"visa","number":"xxxxxxxxxxxx0331","expire_month":"11","expire_year":"2018","first_name":"Joe","last_name":"Shopper","links":[{"href":"[link removed]/CARD-8TT93830P06829326KIOO3XI","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"[link removed]/CARD-8TT93830P06829326KIOO3XI","rel":"delete","method":"DELETE"}]}
```

I am looking for a curl command that would allow me to use the Vaulted Credit Card to bill monthly.

Comment: how do yo make first call in paypal rest api. how can we add authorization as header in request?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the same `/payment` call, but switch out the card data for the `credit_card_id`.

For example;

```
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card_token": {
          "credit_card_id": "CARD-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}
```

Or in cURL:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer xxxxxxxxx" -d '{"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card_token":{"credit_card_id":"CARD-9ND477057R590115SKIOT7OY"}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"7.47","currency":"USD"},"description":"This is the payment transaction description."}]}'
```

There is some more information about this in [the docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/#use-a-stored-credit-card) as well.

Comment: Thank you Master Guru PayPal_Robert.  Since PayPal does not validate credit card information that is stored, is there a list of error codes that go with using stored credit card information?

Comment: Happy to help! These are validated when you call `/payment`; a general list of errors is listed at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#errors (though unfortunately this isn't broken down by resource)

Comment: For each field I am including in the various types transactions, I am intentionally adding too many characters, using too little characters, using illegal characters to gather all the possible error responses.  

Outside of the developers guide, do you know if anybody has a text file that contains all the possible responses you can get.  I am trying to build a parser for every scenario.

Comment: Do you need to get special approval from PayPal to use the Vault API (eg: like you do for the Payouts API)?